# Custom loss function for Multiclass claasification in Scala and Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logistic-regression, loss-function

I want to ask is this possible to write a custom loss function for Multi class Classification in Spark using Scala. I want to code [multi-class logarithmic loss](https://www.kaggle.com/c/telstra-recruiting-network/overview/evaluation) in Scala. I searched Spark documentation but could not get any hint.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Spark 2.2.0 MLlib guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html):

> Currently, only binary classification is supported.. This will likely change when multiclass classification is supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restricted to a particular classification technique I would suggest using XGBoost. It has a Spark-compatible implementation, and it makes it possible to use any loss function provided you can compute is derivative twice.

You can find a tutorial [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/xgboost4j_spark_tutorial.html).

Also the explanation about why it is possible to use a custom loss function can be found [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/model.html#additive-training).